# Easy way for a Windows user to encrypt a file that is to be distributed by e-mail?

Tags: windows, mac, email, encryption, zip

I don't have Windows myself but I need a non-computer-savvy Windows user to e-mail me a file that should be encrypted before it is sent and I must to instruct him on how to do this. Are there any built-in tools in Windows (not sure what version they use) that support encryption that I could tell him to use or do I need to obtain a third party one that works on both Mac and Windows?

Comment: Just send it over WeTransfer - end to end encryption with no faff.

Comment: I disagree that this should be closed as a software recommendation - they have already specified "windows built in tools"

Comment: I would use 7zip and encrypt your archive.  The tool is beautiful on Windows, Mac, and Linux.  It uses AES-256 which should be good enough for whatever you are doing.  Your windows user could right click a folder/file, 7zip -> Add to archive...  In the dialog that appears, the user can enter a password.  The file will show up wherever they clicked the original file.  If you use the 7z format (as opposed to zip), Windows and Mac will know to open it using 7zip.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, Windows does not include anything to encrypt files in a portable manner. You have to use a third-party tool. Most archivers (like 7-Zip, WinZip, WinRAR, …) support encryption. Unfortunately, they are mostly *not* user-friendly enough for a “non-computer-savvy” user, so a detailed guide with screenshots will probably be required.

Also keep in mind that the password should probably not be in the mail message.

---

Alternatively, you could hack together a PowerShell script that encrypts a single file. .NET supports all the required stuff to use strong and secure encryption. The user experience would be… sub-optimal though, to say the least. So, not a good idea.